# NSXMLParser gives error code 4 only sometimes, when the NSData input is always the same

Tags: ios, xcode, nsxmlparser, xmlreader

I am using the class XMLReader to parse some XML from a URL. The XML is successfully parsed sometimes, and sometimes I get:

Error Domain=NSXMLParserErrorDomain Code=4 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (NSXMLParserErrorDomain error 4.)"

The parse is usually successful the first time I run it, after changing something, and it fails after that until I change something else. For example, in the code below, I tried commenting out the [parser release] line, and it parsed successfully. Then I ran it again and back to error code 4.

I log the same input data every time, success or fail.

Any ideas what is going wrong here? I can paste in more code if that would help, but I have isolated the error to be within the NSXMLParser parse method (called in the code below), because it always receives the same data.

Thanks!

edit: I know that error code 4 is an empty document error. But I know my NSData is not empty. So there is something else happening here

```
    - (NSDictionary *)objectWithData:(NSData *)data
{

//data always makes it here, the same data gets logged regardless of parse success

//NSLog(@"%@",data);

// Clear out any old data
[dictionaryStack release];
[textInProgress release];

dictionaryStack = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
textInProgress = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];

// Initialize the stack with a fresh dictionary
[dictionaryStack addObject:[NSMutableDictionary dictionary]];

// Parse the XML
NSXMLParser *parser = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:data];

parser.delegate = self;

[parser setShouldResolveExternalEntities:NO];

BOOL success = [parser parse];

[parser release];


// Return the stack's root dictionary on success
if (success)
{
    NSDictionary *resultDict = [dictionaryStack objectAtIndex:0];

    return resultDict;
}

return nil;
}
```

Comment: Could you please add `NSLog("@"%d", [data length]);` before calling `initWithData`?

Comment: Does it return 2008 even when you get the error?

Comment: Yes, the data is always intact even when I get the error

Comment: Oops, that's unexpected: the error code says it's an empty document error.

Comment: Yes, that is why I am perplexed. I am wondering if anyone knows about the NSXMLParser parse method, and if there are any quirks in its behavior that would cause this

Answer (score 0):

The issue isn't whether `data` is correct at the beginning of your method `objectWithData`; it is whether `data` is correct through out the parse method computation.  You should check that integrity of `data` after the parser completes.

In all likelihood, `data` is returned by the XMLReader but you are not retaining it properly.  Occasionally the computationally intensive parser forces a garbage collection (or pool reclamation) and `data` gets corrupted.

Just do a `[data retain]` at the start of your `objectwithData` method; the problem will then disappear.